# Can't perform a login programmatically

Tags: java, swing, authentication, netbeans-7, htmlunit

Here is what I have done so far by using the [HTMLUNIT](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) library - it is actually the event happening when the button is clicked:

```
private void btnTestActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        try{
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    // Get the first page
    final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://cashialize.com/wp-login.php");

    // Get the form that we are dealing with and within that form, 
    // find the submit button and the field that we want to change.
    final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("loginform");

    final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("wp-submit");
    final HtmlTextInput userField = form.getInputByName("user_login");
    final HtmlTextInput passField = form.getInputByName("passField");

    // Change the value of the text field
    userField.setValueAttribute("admin");
    passField.setValueAttribute("blabla");

    // Now submit the form by clicking the button and get back the second page.
    final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();

    webClient.closeAllWindows();
        }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    }
```

I have followed their guide, but it seems kinda impossibble to me to perform the login. I'm using `netbeans 7.4` and it's my 1st time using the GUI builder. I'm usually working on eclipse(I still cant use to the environment), but I was ensured that it is easier. Anyways. I'm 100% sure that I'm missing something really small, but I'm unable to spot it right now.

Here is the scary exception witch tells nothing to me:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException: elementName=[input] attributeName=[name] attributeValue=[user_login]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm.getInputByName(HtmlForm.java:463)
    at Main.btnTestActionPerformed(Main.java:95)
    at Main.access$000(Main.java:18)
    at Main$1.actionPerformed(Main.java:44)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

**EDIT:**

Console output after the code suggested by Mosty Mostacho

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>
      Cashialize! You can do it! › Log In
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" id="wp-admin-css" href="http://cashialize.com/wp-admin/css/wp-admin.min.css?ver=3.7" type="text/css" media="all"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" id="buttons-css" href="http://cashialize.com/wp-includes/css/buttons.min.css?ver=3.7" type="text/css" media="all"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" id="colors-fresh-css" href="http://cashialize.com/wp-admin/css/colors-fresh.min.css?ver=3.7" type="text/css" media="all"/>
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPasswordInput cannot be cast to com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"/>
  </head>
    at Main.btnTestActionPerformed(Main.java:97)
  <body class="login login-action-login wp-core-ui">
    <div id="login">
      <h1>
    at Main.access$000(Main.java:18)
    at Main$1.actionPerformed(Main.java:44)
        <a href="http://wordpress.org/" title="Powered by WordPress">
          Cashialize! You can do it!
        </a>
      </h1>
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
      <form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="http://cashialize.com/wp-login.php" method="post">
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
        <p>
          <label for="user_login">
            Username
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
            <br/>
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
            <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20"/>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="user_pass">
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
            Password
            <br/>
            <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20"/>
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
          </label>
        </p>
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
        <p class="forgetmenot">
          <label for="rememberme">
            <input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever"/>
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
             Remember Me
          </label>
        </p>
        <p class="submit">
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
          <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="Log In"/>
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
          <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="http://cashialize.com/wp-admin/"/>
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
          <input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1"/>
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
        </p>
      </form>
      <p id="nav">
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        <a href="http://cashialize.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword" title="Password Lost and Found">
          Lost your password?
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        </a>
      </p>
      <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

function wp_attempt_focus(){
setTimeout( function(){ try{
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
d = document.getElementById('user_login');
d.focus();
d.select();
} catch(e){}
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
}, 200);
}

wp_attempt_focus();
if(typeof wpOnload=='function')wpOnload();

//]]>
      </script>
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
      <p id="backtoblog">
        <a href="http://cashialize.com/" title="Are you lost?">
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
          ← Back to Cashialize! You can do it!
        </a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't be scared, it is a simple issue :) What HtmlUnit is telling you with that exception is that in this line:

```
final HtmlTextInput userField = form.getInputByName("user_login");
```

You're not finding anything. In other words, there is no input in the form that has the `name` attribute with the `user_login` value.

I'd recommend you to output the code of the page right after you've fetched it to see the actual code HtmlUnit is processing:

```
final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://cashialize.com/wp-login.php");
System.out.println(page1.asXml());
```

You will find the element you're looking for is not in the form.

Comment: I can see it in the output `<label for="user_login">
            Username
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20"/>
          </label>`

Comment: As HtmlUnit and I have been telling you... :) There is NO attribute with name `user_login`... In your comment it has the value `log` :)

Comment: Oh... But I just used `log` and `pwd` and I'm still getting the scary exception :'(

Comment: You shouldn't. You must be missing something in the output or in the exception.

Comment: No, I'm still getting an exception. :(

Comment: Post the output of that exception and also the relevant Html output from the page that you get from the code I've provided in the answer.

Comment: Just added it to the question.

Comment: The exception you've added is different from the the previous one. It also happens in the following line, which means your first exception is not happening any more (told you :P) so your question should be answered by now. Anyway, I'll give you a hint on this new different exception: The exception says `HtmlPasswordInput cannot be cast to HtmlTextInput` so just change `HtmlTextInput` to `HtmlPasswordInput` in the password line. Remember: If you have more questions, then ask new questions (this one is already answered)

Comment: Wow. It's working now! Thanks for the help. I still can't see the user logged in, but it is probabbly because of the javascript. Who knows. Anyways HUGE thanks for the help!!!